# What is the sample space in conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, polya-urn-model

In conditional probabilities, the sample space at every step is dependent on previous outcomes. How do we then define a sample space? In particular, why is it possible to define the sample space of, for example, Polya's urn model as $\Omega = {[B,W]}^n$ when every sequence of black and white isn't equally likely?

Comment: You can have a sample space in which all outcomes are not equally likely. Who says you cannot?

Comment: then how do you define probability in any meaningful way?

Comment: A sample space is a set of outcomes. There is no requirement for those outcomes to be equally probable (and indeed that is why a probability space includes a *probability function* in its structure).

Comment: thanks, makes sense